# Generating java core dump log file for applets in Linux

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet that is crashing Firefox on Linux.

Can anyone tell me how I can enable the java core dump log file for this applet and where the file would be generated?

Comment: If the JVM is crashing you should get an hserr log file without enabling anything.  Are you not seeing getting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! It was generated automatically in the user home directory.